# Twitter API to use with Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, sbt

I'm building a Spark (3.0.0) streaming application with Scala 2.12 (built with SBT). How do I get tweets from Twitter API, given all libraries for doing this is for Scala <= 2.11.

**EDIT:** sample output that I get when trying to built with the libs:

```
object twitter is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming
[error] import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter, org.apache.bahir.spark-streaming-twitter

Answer (score 1):

In order to import `spark-streaming-twitter` into your Scala 2.12, you need to specify the Scala version in your import:

```
resolvers += "twitter_2" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "1.6.3"
```

This call forces to fetch the scala 2.11 version from artifactory. The import probably tried was:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.6.3"
```

The `sbt` searches for `spark-streaming-twitter_2.12` in case your scala build version is 2.12, which does exist in [maven atifactory](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter).

Having said that, you need to understand the [binary compatibility of scala releases](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/binary-compatibility-of-scala-releases.html), before you do such thing.

After this import you can call:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
```

Comment: There is no 2.12 version "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter". I dont think this actually answers question.