# Twitter data Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter

The following:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
```

Provides the following error:

```
object twitter is not a member of the package org.apache.spark.streaming
```

I'm using scala and spark.

Comment: Did you include the dependency?

Comment: scala version 2.12

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 i dont get it how do i add this in scala IDE

Comment: do you use sbt, maven or gradle?, if sbt you can use sbt plugin: https://everythingwhat.com/how-do-i-install-sbt-plugin-in-scala-ide

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241084/2359227) help you?